# CSV gets saved in a weird format

Tags: python, csv

```
...
with open('commands2.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for i in range(len(output)):
        if i != 0 and i != len(output) - 1: # skip first and last since they are not commands
            line = output[i]
            line = line.lstrip()
            #print('line\n', line)
            cmd = line.split(' ', 1)
            if len(cmd) > 1 and len(cmd[0]) > 1:
                description = cmd[1].lstrip().replace('\r', '')
            print(str(cmd[0]), str(description))
            res.append(str(cmd[0]))
            writer.writerows([str(cmd[0]), str(description)])
return res
```

In my function, it tries to save a parsed command and description. If I print them (cmd[0] and description) out it looks like,

```
('aaa', 'Show AAA configuration and operational data')
('aal', 'Show AAL data')
('access-lists', 'Access lists')
('address-pool', 'Local address pool')
('adjacency', 'Adjacency information')
('af-ea', 'AF-EA Platform details(cisco-support)')
('alarm-mgr', 'Show alarm mgr traces')
('alarms', 'Show Alarms associated with XR')
```

So, it's parsed correctly. But when I save it as I did in my code, the file looks like this:

[image]

It's weird because when I print it, it's not like that.

Any help?

Comment: use `writerow() ` without **s** at the end of name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('commands2.csv', 'wb') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, dialect='excel', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

Try to open it with 'wb', and set dialect to 'excel'. It works for me.

Oops, writerows([[]]):

```
writer.writerows([[str(cmd[0]), str(description)]])
```

Comment: Great! It works. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```py
writer.writerows([str(cmd[0]), str(description)])
```

Considering the help function of `writer.writerow**s**`, it suggests that this function accepts the sequence of sequences.
Use `writer.writerow` instead. Existing code would work as it is.